# Using `itertools` to combine DataFrame columns

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, iteration

I have a `DataFrame` which looks like this toy example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = np.array([
    [20.078,19.679,19.585,19.406,19.37,14.97,13.992,20.122,20.736],
    [20.443,19.115,18.918,18.749,18.698,14.638,14.041,21.646,21.456],
    [19.723,19.593,19.353,19.175,19.258,15.193,14.354,21.122,21.09],
    [19.683,19.393,19.273,18.995,18.95,15.545,14.53,22.465,20.091],
    [19.769,19.233,19.083,18.983,18.768,14.978,14.224,21.684,20.314],
    [19.908,19.5,19.065,18.838,18.354,13.837,13.016,21.307,21.234]
])

df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns = ['u', 'g', 'r', 'i', 'zmag', 'W1', 'W2', 'NUV', 'FUV'])
```

and I want to combine the columns pairwise into subtractive combinations, which is what this snippet does:

```
df['FUV_NUV'] = dataset['FUV'] - dataset['NUV']
df['FUV_u'] = df['FUV'] - df['u']
df['u_g'] = df['u'] - df['g']
df['g_r'] = df['g'] - df['r']
df['r_i'] = df['r'] - df['i']
df['i_z'] = df['i'] - df['zmag']
df['z_W1'] = df['zmag'] - df['W1']
df['W1_W2'] = df['W1'] - df['W2']
```

But of course, there's a nicer way to do this, which I found [here](https://www.titanwolf.org/Network/q/685e646b-8e72-426e-a3f1-f54330310302/y):

```
combs = list(chain.from_iterable(combinations(df.columns, i)
                                 for i in range(2, len(df.columns) + 1)))
for cols in combs:
    df['_'.join(cols)] = df.loc[:, cols].sum(axis=1)
```

However, this produces *all* combinations (such as `u+g+W1+W2+...`) additively.

How can I change it so that it

1. iterates through the columns to produce all combinations of two columns maximum (eg: u-g, u-r, u-i, u-zmag, ...)
2. subtractive (i.e. not `sum`)?

Comment: "iterates through the columns to produce all combinations of two columns maximum" Hint 1: what do you think the `for i in range(2, len(df.columns) + 1)` part means? Hint 2: Look at the code **in the question** on that page you cite.

Comment: "subtractive (i.e. not sum)?" Well, did you try putting `pandas difference of columns` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=pandas+difference+of+columns)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate the list a 2 elem combinations of adjacent columns with wraparound using this list comprehension
Then you could generate additional columns by iterating through this list

```
comb = [(x, df.columns[(i+1) % len(df.columns)]) for i, x in enumerate(df.columns)]


for x, y in comb:
  df[f'{x}_{y}'] = df[x] - df[y]
```

this produces the output:

```
        u       g       r       i    zmag      W1      W2     NUV     FUV    u_g    g_r    r_i  i_zmag  zmag_W1  W1_W2  W2_NUV  NUV_FUV  FUV_u
0  20.078  19.679  19.585  19.406  19.370  14.970  13.992  20.122  20.736  0.399  0.094  0.179   0.036    4.400  0.978  -6.130   -0.614  0.658
1  20.443  19.115  18.918  18.749  18.698  14.638  14.041  21.646  21.456  1.328  0.197  0.169   0.051    4.060  0.597  -7.605    0.190  1.013
2  19.723  19.593  19.353  19.175  19.258  15.193  14.354  21.122  21.090  0.130  0.240  0.178  -0.083    4.065  0.839  -6.768    0.032  1.367
3  19.683  19.393  19.273  18.995  18.950  15.545  14.530  22.465  20.091  0.290  0.120  0.278   0.045    3.405  1.015  -7.935    2.374  0.408
4  19.769  19.233  19.083  18.983  18.768  14.978  14.224  21.684  20.314  0.536  0.150  0.100   0.215    3.790  0.754  -7.460    1.370  0.545
5  19.908  19.500  19.065  18.838  18.354  13.837  13.016  21.307  21.234  0.408  0.435  0.227   0.484    4.517  0.821  -8.291    0.073  1.326
```

Comment: How can I make sure that all possible non-repetitive two-element combinations are produced? For example, `u_zmag` and `W2_i` but not `i_W2` ?

Comment: do you want all 2-elem combinations?

Comment: Ideally, yes, but non-repetitive.

Comment: @Jim421616, its not super clear to me what you want. can you update the question with the combinations that you'd expect given this dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Try out `df.diff(axis=1)` and see the function's [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html).

> Calculates the difference of a Dataframe element compared with another element in the Dataframe (default is element in previous row).

When we use `axis=1`, this function gets the difference between one column and the previous column. So you might have to re-order your columns for this function to work properly for your purpose.

---

Here is another option that uses loops.

In my opinion, the method using `itertools` is less readable than simply writing out the columns you are subtracting.

I would also suggest using the `df.loc[]` syntax when setting data on a dataframe.

```py
pairs = [
    ("FUV", "NUV"),
    ("FUV", "u"),
    ("u", "g"),
    ("g", "r"),
    ("r", "i"),
    ("i", "zmag"),
    ("zmag", "W1"),
    ("W1", "W2"),
]

for col1, col2 in pairs:
    new_col_name = f"{col1}_{col2}"
    df.loc[:, new_col_name] = df[col1] - df[col2]
```